# Custom keyboard tab order in html4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to manage keyboard tab order functionality, I am using a template for header, footer and sidebar where many  anchor element & input element exists. In template content we can not put and `tabindex` attribute which is not in my control.

Middle part of template is my work area, where I created a form and some element

```
<fieldset id="myWorkArea">
    <div class="fieldrow">
        <label for="input1">Class</label>
        <input  id="input1"/>
        <a id="help1" href="#">what's this?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldrow">
        <label for="input2">Class</label>
        <input id="input2"/>
        <a id="help2" href="#">what's this?</a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

In above code I want to cursor tabbing in below id order.

```
#help1 > #input1
#help2 > #input2
```

Is any approach to control keyboard tabbing order in only `#myWorkArea` fieldset elements as we can not put tabindex for all element in page?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have no access to the template, you can still add the *tabindex* attribute programmatically.

Here you have a snippet:

```js
var tabindex = 1;

$('#myWorkArea .fieldrow').each( function() {
 $('a', this).attr('tabindex', tabindex++);
 $('input', this).attr('tabindex', tabindex++);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="myWorkArea">
    <div class="fieldrow">
        <label for="input1">Class</label>
        <input  id="input1"/>
        <a id="help1" href="#">what's this?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldrow">
        <label for="input2">Class</label>
        <input id="input2"/>
        <a id="help2" href="#">what's this?</a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks alot, Is any way to solve this issue by using HTML attribute or element as i don't want to bind it in javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your comment, I thought that you couldn't modify the HTML: "In template content we can not put and tabindex attribute which is not in my control". May you give us a more complete explanation? Perhaps we can use a CSS trick.

Comment: We can do anything only inside the  element <fieldset id="myWorkArea"> and outside part of this fieldset is not in my control. I am looking for non js solution.

Comment: So you could actually include the ´tabindex´ manually, rIght? It is not a solution because there are too many elements (just checking out if I understood you). The default tab order is _almost_ what you want, you need just to change the order of the ´input´ and ´a´ elements. Then, with CSS, you can force the ´a´ element to be on the right side of the ´input´.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the tab index programmatically using javascript as David mentioned in his answer.

Or If you want you can control the taborder functionality by binding your own event to only  these elements like below code.

Working [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3w0nakze/)

```
$(function(){
    var inputs = $('a#help1, a#help2,input#input1, input#input2');
            $(inputs).bind('keydown', function (e) {     
               var self = $(this), form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'), focusable, next;
           //check keycode for tabbing     
           if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                    switch($(this).attr("id")){                     
                        case "help1":
                            next=$('#input1');
                            break;
                          case "help2":
                            next=$('#input2');
                            break;
                          case "input1":
                            next=$('#help2');
                            break;  
                          case "input2":
                            next=$('#help1');
                            break; 
                           }                    
                    next.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot,
Is any way to solve this issue by using HTML attribute or element as i don't want to bind it in javascript?